# python-nmap on MacOS in PyCharm/Visual Studio---Nmap Requires root privileges

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, nmap

I am getting the same error in both pycharm and visual studio code.

`nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'You requested a scan type which requires root privileges.\nQUITTING!\n'`

I tried open the applications with sudo, but same error is here.

```
/Applications % sudo open PyCharm\ CE.app/
```

I enabled 'root' in macos, it worked that way, but I don't prefer it much.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If you try to use `nmap` directly in console/terminal  then you should have the same problem. It is problem with program `nmap`, not with Python wrapper/module. And I have the same problem on Linux. But I never bother this. Problem can make program `nmap` or maybe library `pcap` used by `nmap`, `wireshark`, and other similar tools to access network device with special functions.

Comment: I found article [Why Does Nmap Need Root Privileges?](https://www.infosecmatter.com/why-does-nmap-need-root-privileges/) and there is some solution for program `nmap` but it may not work for Python module because it needs to run program `nmap` with extra argument. But there is also link to [Running nmap as an unprivileged user](https://secwiki.org/w/Running_nmap_as_an_unprivileged_user) which uses `enviroment variable` instead of extra argument in `nmap`